# Vue undefined data before data fetched

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a problem with some data. 
When I load my dashboard it gives me the error that it cant read amount of undefined. 
When i fresh reload the page it works. 
So it is the place when i've logged in the data doesn't work. 
but on reload it works how it should.

I have tried with v-if before the chart in both components and trying to define an object and fill it on the chart component. and then saying v-if. nothing works. can anyone help?

I have 3 components

1. Login (component pushing to dashboard on succesfull login)
2. Dashboard (component with imported charts)
3. Charts (here is the charts generated)

login: heres where i login and push route to dashboard

```
<template>
  <button @onclick="login()"> Login </button>
</template>
<script>
  heres the login functions that initialize the session i fill with 
  user data.
</script>
```

dashboard: and here do i fill the session with the data i want.

```
<template>
  <p v-if="company.thirtydayScore"> {{company.thirtydaysscore}} </p>
  <chart> </chart>
</template>
<script>
 data(){
   company{
     thirtydaysScore: null
     amount: null and so on
   }
 },
 async beforeMount () {
  await this.fetchData()
  await this.$eventHub.$emit('runToday')
 }
 methods: {
   fetchData(){
     heres api call and fetching of data
     this.company = response.data
     this.$session.set('data', this.company)
   }
 }
</script>
```

3. chart

   ```
    <template>
     <myChart> </myChart>
    </template>
    <script>
     data(){
      company{
         thirtydaysScore: null
         amount: null and so on
      }
    },
    async beforeMount () {
     var self = this
     await this.$eventHub.on('runToday'){
       self.fillData()
      }
    }
    methods: {
      fillData(){
        here do i fill the data i use in charts from this.$session.get('data')
      }
    }
    </script>
   ```

Error image

[image: error]

login hastebin: https://hastebin.com/imeqaxevim.xml

dashboard hastebin: https://hastebin.com/ixuyiroyuy.xml

chart hastebin: https://hastebin.com/iheqiditiy.xml

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my problem is exactly the same, but I have encountered this error with vee-validate a lot. Seems something with a mismatch between initiating the data and the component. There probably will be a better solution, but I always solve these errors very pragmatically with `v-if = "company && company.amount"`.

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using? Shouldn't data return a function? Like this: `data () { return { company: {amount} }}`

Comment: i have linked the hastebin ;)

Comment: @AndersBootsmannLarsen yeah saw that after I posted haha. It looks good to me. No clue. I think you need to debug this with vue devtools to see what is actually in data at the time of error. At first glance code seems fine, so devtools is the only way.